# Removing invalid characters from amazon cloud search sdf

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

While trying to post the data extracted from a pdf file to a amazon cloud search domain for indexing, the indexing failed due to invalid chars in the data.

How can i remove these invalid charecters before posting to the search end point?

I tried escaping and replacing the chars, but didn't work.

Comment: CloudSearch supports only English for now

Comment: the documents are in english.

Comment: CloudSearch now supports most languages in the unicode table: `\u0020-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem using the solution available [here](http://maxharp3r.wordpress.com/2008/05/15/pythons-minidom-xml-and-illegal-unicode-characters/)

```
RE_XML_ILLEGAL = u'([\u0000-\u0008\u000b-\u000c\u000e-\u001f\ufffe-\uffff])' + \
                 u'|' + \
                 u'([%s-%s][^%s-%s])|([^%s-%s][%s-%s])|([%s-%s]$)|(^[%s-%s])' % \
                  (unichr(0xd800),unichr(0xdbff),unichr(0xdc00),unichr(0xdfff),
                   unichr(0xd800),unichr(0xdbff),unichr(0xdc00),unichr(0xdfff),
                   unichr(0xd800),unichr(0xdbff),unichr(0xdc00),unichr(0xdfff))
x = u"<foo>text\u001a</foo>"
x = re.sub(RE_XML_ILLEGAL, "?", x)
```

Answer (score 3):

I was getting an error like this when uploading document to CloudSearch (using aws sdk / json):

> Error with source for field content_stemmed: Validation error for field 'content_stemmed': Invalid codepoint B

The solution for me, as documented by AWS (reference below), was to remove invalid characters from the document prior to uploading:

For example this is what I did using javascript:

```
const cleaned = someFieldValue.replace(
  /[^\u0009\u000a\u000d\u0020-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD]/g, 
  ''
)
```

[ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/preparing-data.html):

> Both JSON and XML batches can only contain UTF-8 characters that are valid in XML. Valid characters are the control characters tab (0009), carriage return (000D), and line feed (000A), and the legal characters of Unicode and ISO/IEC 10646. FFFE, FFFF, and the surrogate blocks D800–DBFF and DC00–DFFF are invalid and will cause errors.
>
> You can use the following regular expression to match invalid characters so you can remove them: /[^\u0009\u000a\u000d\u0020-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD]/